# How to use string argument in Select statement in BigQuery UDF?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is my code for Google BigQuery UDF.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `my_dataset.ST_EXTENT_TABLE`
(tableName STRING)
RETURNS STRUCT<xmin FLOAT64, ymin FLOAT64, xmax FLOAT64, ymax FLOAT64>
AS (
    WITH data AS ( SELECT geom FROM tableName)
    SELECT ST_EXTENT(geom) AS box FROM data
);
```

In "SELECT geom FROM tableName", tableName should be replaced with passed value.

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by string argument? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: string argument is "tableName" in my UDF

Comment: I want to use my UDF like this,  SELECT my_dataset.ST_EXTENT_TABLE("tableNameExample")

Comment: Hi @ZhefengJin, can you clarify what is passed value?

Comment: passed value is table name , like "siros-tech.lg_well_data.section_for_label"

Comment: still not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement, it is not possible to dynamically pass the table name in UDF. As an alternative you can write a dynamic sql query where you can pass the table name dynamically. Using [Execute Immediate](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate)  you can execute those dynamic queries and get the result.

You can try the below sample query.

**Query:**

```
DECLARE query String;
SET
  query = '''with cte as (
    select filename from %s limit 10
)
select * from cte''';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  FORMAT(query,"bigquery-public-data.bbc_news.fulltext")
```

**Output:**

[image]